# RHEL 8 Qt 4.8 packages

Tags: redhat, rhel8, qt

I need Qt4 packages for RHEL 8. "yum search qt" on RHEL 8.0 reveals only Qt5 packages.

Are there any Qt4.8 (or later) packages for RHEL 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like getpagespeed has built some binaries here: https://centos.pkgs.org/8/getpagespeed-x86_64/

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. [Upstream support for qt 4 ended in 2015.](https://www.qt.io/blog/2014/11/27/qt-4-8-x-support-to-be-extended-for-another-year)

Start a port to Qt 5. Until then, run in a Qt 4 environment like EL 7.